# Cambiar color titulo sección nav drawer

Tags: android, xml

Buen día, ¿que propiedad debo cambiar para cambiar el color de los títulos en el nav drawer? en Internet he encontrado como cambiar la letra de los items pero no la de el titulo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de configuración del drawer, tiene la opción de cambiar el color de los textos pero no los títulos

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@drawable/prueba"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary2"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary2"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main_usuarios"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_usuarios_drawer" />
```

Comment: Estaria bueno tener el codigo para facilitarte nuestra ayuda.

Comment: Arriba lo coloque, gracias

Comment: @AlvaroFabianM agrega activity_main_usuarios_drawer.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pueder cambiar el color de esta forma:

En tu archivo **activity_main_usuarios_drawer.xml** agregar un **identificador**:

```
<item android:title="@string/opciones"
      android:id="@+id/opciones">
```

Y en tu actividad principal agregar este código, que te permitirá obtener la referencia y poder cambiar el color del texto:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
MenuItem tools =  navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.opciones);
SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(tools.getTitle());
spanString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(this, 
R.color.color_notification)), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
tools.setTitle(spanString);
```

De esta forma me funciona a mi, espero que te sea útil.

Comment: Gracias funciona

Comment: Me da gusto que te funcionara, puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada,  haz click en el check al costado de la respuesta, saludos.

Comment: @AlvaroFabianM ninguna de tus preguntas tienen respuesta aceptada, es importante que aceptes la respuesta si es que fue correcta, esto para que promuevas otros usuarios te ayuden, además otros usuarios sabrían como resolver la misma problemática que tuviste,
 un saludo!

Comment: Creo que entonces tengo una confusión, cunado me funciona clickeo la flecha hacia arriba

Comment: Creo que esto aclarara tu duda amigo  https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas